# Getting Client username in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, iis

I am trying to get the client domain\username from a VB.Net application.

When I use

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

I get the results I want. But only when running it locally through visual studio / iisexpress
But When I try to put it on my IIS 7.5 (on windows 2008 server), the program will stop when it gets to running this line of code. It just stops.

using this

```
on Error GoTo test_Error

test_Error: 
Error_Handler(writes errors to a sql log)
```

The error is not caught.

So what is going on?
Thanks!

UPDATE: 
Using the 'Try-catch' here

```
            Try
               MsgBox(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name)
            Catch ex As Exception
               MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

and still cannot get an error message to show (Chrome broswer, yes popups are enabled)

Using chrome developer tools I found this was the error:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Comment: What authentication methods are configured in the IIS site?

Comment: Also, that is a REALLY bad way of handling errors. Check out Try / Catch blocks.

Comment: `"It just stops"` - How have you validated that it's this exact statement which causes the problem?

Comment: can you instead of labels just do try - catch and get real error message?

Comment: @David Since I have a logging function, I am able to log right before I try to throw this into a MsgBox and then right after.  So my log looks like "sub started" , "trying to get username now" then stops. I will try a 'do catch', but was taught this method of error catching from a VB professional. Will return with my findings.

Comment: Updated with results from the try-catch

Comment: check authentication method and users in iis, go to iis manager

Comment: @maku what settings should I look for in the authentication method / users? I am not really a microsoft or .net programmer at all. I see that only Anonymous Authentication is enabled. All other forms (Forms, Windows, Basic, ASP.Net Impersonation) are all disabled.

Comment: How long do you wait for it?  Because it's probably trying to do a AD permissions lookup to a non-existent/non-accessible domain, I would guess at least 30-120 seconds before it would throw the error.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I thought of that as well, I left it for about 5 minutes and never got anything. I will try this again though and just let it sit.

Comment: http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/vault-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-To-Enable-Windows-Authentication-on-Windows-2008-After-Installing-Vault-Server-s.html follow these steps. please use google :) google is a friend
steps 6 and 7 is optional

Comment: @maku wouldn't windows authentication then require users accessing the website to HAVE a windows account? For example, if the user was using an Android phone to browse my web app, would they still be able to connect?

Comment: @Christopher: Yes, I believe the `WindowsIdentity` is really only useful for Intranet apps. As you mentioned, it wouldn't work for "outside" users like someone browsing from their phone. If the web app is accessible to the world and requires logins, you may want to look into options like ASP.NET Membership Provider or ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: `MsgBox` is for Winforms. You're using ASP.NET. What happens if you do `MsgBox("Hello")` at the start of your code?

Comment: @JohnSaunders MsgBox works as a 'popup' window for ASP.Net but I would never use it oustide of testing

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
```

This will return raw authenticated username.